# How to change card view to list view in Assets sidepanel in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem

I want to change the Assets sidepanel from card view into list view. My assets full name is not visible. How can we change this to list view?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is an option for assets while authoring a page. If you want to see list view of assets, you would go to the DAM and see it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this into a "List View" is not supported or possible via OOTB APIs. The asset cards are displayed as [Coral.Masonry](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.Masonry.html)

> You could probably change it, but it would require quite a few lines of CSS and a Js update to change the `columnWidth` on the Coral.Masonry element. Which would be a temporary hack.

If your concern is showing the full asset name, you can do that with CSS:

1. Create clientlibrary with `categories="[cq.authoring.editor.hook]"`
2. add the following CSS

```
.sidepanel-tab-assets .editor-Card-asset coral-card-title {
  white-space: initial !important;
}
```

The asset cards should now display the full name.

[image: before css change]
[image: after css changee]

Comment: Thanks. I ll take this workaround as answer as it solves the issue faced.

Answer (score 0):

As Iscmaro mentioned there is no list view options for assets while authoring the page. As you want to see the full name of the asset, if you can hover on the image, you get the name displayed as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: assets]

Comment: Hover doesnt work consistently, esp in IE browser. So this doesnt help me :(